# How to add an icon in the left column of Intellij idea edit window?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmtHJ.png)

Just like the Spring plugin. I want to add a clickable icon to the left of the code editor.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such icon using the `codeInsight.lineMarkerProvider` extension ponit.

Check the IntelliJ Platform SDK Docs - [Line Marker Provider](https://www.jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/line_marker_provider.html) for more details.